# CefDOMVisitor Visit method never called?

Tags: c++, chromium-embedded

I want to detect document.ready via CefDOMVisitor `Visit` call and wrote code like below, but after page load I get logs `DOMVisitor()` and `~DOMVisitor()`, no `DOMVisitor::Visit`. Why is "Visit" not called?

```cpp
class DOMVisitor : public CefDOMVisitor {
public:
    DOMVisitor(){
        App::Log(L"DOMVisitor()", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    };
    ~DOMVisitor(){
        App::Log(L"~DOMVisitor()", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    };
    virtual void Visit(CefRefPtr<CefDOMDocument> document) override{
        App::Log(L"DOMVisitor::Visit", __FUNCTION__, __FILE__, __LINE__);
    };

    IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(DOMVisitor);
};
```

```cpp
class LoadHandler : public CefLoadHandler {
public:
    virtual void OnLoadEnd(CefRefPtr<CefBrowser> browser,
        CefRefPtr<CefFrame> frame,
        int httpStatusCode) override{
        CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();

        if (frame && frame->IsMain() && httpStatusCode == 200)
        {
            frame->VisitDOM(new DOMVisitor);
        }
    };

    IMPLEMENT_REFCOUNTING(LoadHandler);
};
```

fin.

I run the RENDERER process and the BROWSER process at the same time, and `LoadHandler` is implemented in the BROWSER process. However, the `CefFrame::VisitDOM()` method can only be called from the rendering process, so `DOMVisitor` needs to be implemented in the RENDERER process rather than implemented and called in the BROWSER process.

Comment: have you tried using a debugger inspecting what happened inside frame->VisitDOM?

Comment: `OnLoadEnd()` is called from the UI thread, you ensure that with `CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD();`. This method can only be called from the render process: `CefFrame::VisitDOM()`. See https://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefFrame.html#VisitDOM(CefRefPtr%3CCefDOMVisitor%3E).

Comment: @haleyk, i tried using a debugger inspecting what happened inside frame->VisitDOM, and  I found that it made a return here. Is this normal?```void CefFrameCToCpp::VisitDOM(CefRefPtr<CefDOMVisitor> visitor) {
  shutdown_checker::AssertNotShutdown();

  cef_frame_t* _struct = GetStruct();
  if (CEF_MEMBER_MISSING(_struct, visit_dom))
    return;```

Comment: @273K, I run the RENDERER process and the BROWSER process at the same time, and LoadHandler is implemented in the BROWSER process. Here I remove CEF_REQUIRE_UI_THREAD(); and the execution result is the same

Comment: Next, I will try to implement DOMVisitor in the rendering process.

Comment: @273K very thanks, I implemented `LoadHandler` in the browser process, implemented `DOMVisitor` in the render process, received messages through `OnProcessMessageReceived` and sent messages through `frame->SendProcessMessage`, and successfully obtained the `Visit` function call result of `DOMVisitor`.